# How should I import a component from my addon into the addon's dummy test?

Tags: ember-cli

I'm writing an addon that defines a `StickyHeaderListComponent` under `addon`, and import it according to the Components section of the [addons section of the guides](http://www.ember-cli.com/#developing-addons-and-blueprints).

I'd like to write some tests + use the dummy app, but the dummy app doesn't have access to `{{sticky-header-list}}`. How can I import it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `app` folder is merged into the application which consumes the addon during the build.
So, The file `sticky-header-list.js` should be under `app/components`.
Best practice is to write a mixin which will include the entire code of the component under `addon/mixins`

```js
// addon/mixins/sticky-header-list.js

export default Ember.Mixin.create({
  //Put all the component code here
});
```

And the actual component will be

```js
// app/components/sticky-header-list.js

import StickyHeaderListMixin from '<your-addon-name>/mixins/sticky-header-list';
export default Ember.Component.extend(StickyHeaderListMixin);
```

In that way, a developer that will install your addon can choose to use the mixin, since the component code is not available at dev time.
The mixin will be importable under the path  `<your-addon-name>/mixins/sticky-header-list.js`.
You can see an example in my [ember-cli-lightbox addon](https://github.com/ramybenaroya/ember-cli-lightbox).